# pixel color detection on system screen

Tags: java

Is there is any way to find color name of pixel on screen under pointer?

```
              robot=new Robot();
              Point  coord = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation(); 
              color = robot.getPixelColor((int)coord.getX(), (int)coord.getY());

              hexString = Integer.toHexString(color.getRGB());
              hexString = hexString.substring(2, hexString.length());
```

now i want color name of this hex value (as blue/green/black etc)... how can i do this?

Comment: You can't (feasibly) do this.  The closet you can get is comparing the `color` with the predefined colors in the `Color` class, but this won't match every possible color, just a small number of premitives

Comment: I'd cut out the whole pixel business, if I'd asked this question

Answer (score 2):

Compare it with the Color.RED etc, and take the one closest to the input.

Or you could use wolfram alpha API http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/libraries.html

FFF0F5 is for example called Lavender Blush and if you type FFF0F4 it would suggest this as the closest

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%23FFF0F5